# Chrome rendering issue with overflow hidden

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, rendering

I'm trying to work out why only the before and after elements are being rendered in the below example and how I would go about getting the span rendered as well.

The problem seems to only occur in Chrome, though I've only tested Opera, IE, Safari and Firefox as well.

Unfortunately as I'm not 100% sure why this is occurring I can't provide any further information.

http://jsfiddle.net/ddoticus/2egfkpu4/

```
dd {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s;
}
```

I believe the above code is the problem though.

If you open and close title 3 and then open it again it renders the span's background as white.

If anyone could explain a- why this is happening and b- an effective workaround that'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it was highlighting is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have solved itself, it appears Google must have done an update or something as this, and the original problem I was having that this question was based on, has now been fixed.
If anyone can provide any explanation as to why this occurred that would be very much appreciated, but for now the problem has been resolved.